# How do I generate my application using CodeFluent Entities and Telerik Controls?

Tags: wpf, telerik, visual-studio-2015, codefluent

I've seen a blog on CodeFluent Entities's site about [auto-generating a WPF UI](http://blog.codefluententities.com/2014/02/14/generate-your-application-with-codefluent-entities-and-syncfusion-part-2/) using CodeFluent Entities and Syncfusion but I have Telerik WPF controls and wanted to know whether anyone has already done this and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: OK, thanks for the prompt feedback. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I've tried to visit blog(dot)codefluententities(dot)com and no longer exists. But what's more scary it that www(dot)codefluententities(dot)com now redirects you to a date's web...

Answer (score 0):

[The Syncfusion producer](https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeFluent-Entities/tree/master/Samples/SoftFluent.Samples.Syncfusion) is based on a template, so you can get a copy of the code and replace the Syncfusion controls by the Telerik controls in the template files. For instance you can replace the Syncfusion DataGrid by a Telerik DataGrid in the file [EntityView.xaml.tpl](https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeFluent-Entities/blob/master/Samples/SoftFluent.Samples.Syncfusion/ContactManager.SyncfusionTemplate/SyncfusionWPF/UserControls/EntityView.xaml.tpl).